# Proof of the Baire category theorem for complete metric spaces: why do I have to have shrinking closed sets?

Tags: general-topology, baire-category, complete-spaces

The proof of the Baire category theorem for complete metric spaces involves, among other things, constructing a sequence $(F_n)_n$ of closed sets such that $\operatorname{diam} F_n \to 0$.  This gives you a point in $\bigcap_n F_n$, concluding the proof.

Why do I have to have closed sets of shrinking diameter?  Making the size of the sets small enough to obtain a point in all of them seems a bit counterintuitive.  It is easy to see that I want the closed sets to be *bounded*, since if I take, for instance, $F_n := [n, \infty)$ in the complete metric space $\mathbb R$, then the intersection is empty.  However, I cannot see why I need to have the diameters of the closed sets to be really small in the limit and tend to zero.

Question: what is an example of a sequence of closed sets in a completely metric space, every set of which is bounded, such that the intersection of all the closed sets is empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$. $X$ is not complete in the usual metric, but it’s a $G_\delta$ in the complete metric space $\Bbb R$, so it’s completely metrizable: there is a metric $d$ on $X$ such that $\langle X,d\rangle$ is complete, and $d$ generates the usual topology. Let $q\in\Bbb Q$, and let $\langle q_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a strictly increasing sequence of rational numbers converging to $q$ in $\Bbb R$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $I_n=(q_n,q)\cap X$; each $I_n$ is clopen in $X$, and $I_{n+1}\subsetneqq I_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, but $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}I_n=\varnothing$.

In fact $X$ is well-known to be homeomorphic to $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ with the product topology, where $\Bbb N$ is given the discrete topology. If $d$ is the discrete metric on $\Bbb N$, a complete metric $\rho$ on $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ is given by

$$\rho(x,y)=\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}\frac{d(x_n,y_n)}{2^n}\;,$$

where $x=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle,y=\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\in\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$.

Comment: Thank you.  Is it easy to see that $I_n$ is still bounded according to the new metric $d$?

Comment: @Pteromys: The whole space is, if you use the one in the last paragraph: $\rho(x,y)\le 2$ for all $x,y\in X$. If $d$ is any metric on a space $X$, the metric $d'(x,y)=\min\{d(x,y),1\}$ is a bounded metric that generates the same topology, and it’s complete iff $d$ is. Thus, boundedness really doesn’t tell you anything here.

Answer (score 2):

In a separable  Hilbert space (e.g. $\ell^2$) with orthonormal basis $e_1, e_2, \ldots$, let $S_n = \{e_j :\; j \ge n\}$.  This is a sequence of nested closed subsets, each of diameter $\sqrt{2}$, whose intersection is empty.